# Как убрать обводку вокруг стрелки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос для тех, кто работал с плагином slick для слайдеров (хотя, может, это не важно). Как убрать обводку вокруг стрелки и картинки при нажатии на неё? Добавлять `.., ..:hover, ..:visited` и т.д. пробовал, не помогло

Comment: если при нажатии, то это псевдокласс `:focus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего у вашей кнопки есть `outline`, который создает рамку.

```css
.aloha {
  background-color: red;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.aloha:focus, .aloha:hover, .aloha:active {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="aloha">Click Me</button>
```